# Unable to store array of hash as a string in Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am converting array of hash into a string then store it in the smart contract. It is throwing error as;

> transact to Test.set errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected number in JSON at position 46

Array: [0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c,0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c]

It is working fine when length of array is 2, more than this it is not working.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
   string public t;
   function set(string _t) public {
       t = _t;
   }
}
```

Conversion from array to string is handle by a separate javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly where you are going wrong since you do not share the JavaScript which converts the array to a string, but in theory what you are doing should be just fine.

I recommend that you use the `JSON.stringify()` function to convert your array into a proper string.

```
>> let arr = new Array(10).fill("0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c")

>> arr
Array(10) [ "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c" ]

>> JSON.stringify(arr)
"[\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\",\"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c\"]"
```

This last string should have no such syntax errors. To undo the stringify, just use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Thank you it works. Actually I was using toString() for conversion. Don't know what exactly is the difference between 2.

Comment: Thank you the string in your it works. How it is adding '\' ? When I am doing JSON.stringify() it is just making it in string format, no '\' were there and without those '\' it is giving the same error.

Comment: The backslash is an "escape character" telling the JavaScript to parse the following character as a character, rather than code syntax. This is how you can use quotation marks within a string. `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are standard in JavaScript, and should pretty much always be your go to when doing things like this.